# Unable to Build and Compile Toree

Tags: java, ubuntu, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, apache-toree

I'm having errors when running `make dev` and `make release` and `make jupyter` in toree when building from master.

My machine is Ubuntu 16.04

```
root@ubuntu-2gb-sgp1-01:/home/incubator-toree# uname -r
4.4.0-47-generic
```

when running `make release` in toree root i get

```
root@ubuntu-2gb-sgp1-01:/home/incubator-toree# make release
APACHE_SPARK_VERSION=2.0.0 VERSION=0.2.0.dev1-incubating IS_SNAPSHOT=true sbt toree/assembly
Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=1024M'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Makefile:110: recipe for target 'target/scala-2.11/toree-assembly-0.2.0.dev1-incubating-SNAPSHOT.jar' failed
make: *** [target/scala-2.11/toree-assembly-0.2.0.dev1-incubating-SNAPSHOT.jar] Error 1
root@ubuntu-2gb-sgp1-01:/home/incubator-toree#
```

`make jupyter`

```
root@ubuntu-2gb-sgp1-01:/home/incubator-toree# make jupyter
APACHE_SPARK_VERSION=2.0.0 VERSION=0.2.0.dev1-incubating IS_SNAPSHOT=true sbt toree/assembly
Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=1024M'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Makefile:110: recipe for target 'target/scala-2.11/toree-assembly-0.2.0.dev1-incubating-SNAPSHOT.jar' failed
make: *** [target/scala-2.11/toree-assembly-0.2.0.dev1-incubating-SNAPSHOT.jar] Error 1
```

I installed java through `apt-get install default-jdk`

```
root@ubuntu-2gb-sgp1-01:/home/incubator-toree# java -version
openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)
root@ubuntu-2gb-sgp1-01:/home/incubator-toree#
```

`make release`

```
root@ubuntu-2gb-sgp1-01:/home/incubator-toree# make release
APACHE_SPARK_VERSION=2.0.0 VERSION=0.2.0.dev1-incubating IS_SNAPSHOT=true sbt toree/assembly
Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=1024M'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Makefile:110: recipe for target 'target/scala-2.11/toree-assembly-0.2.0.dev1-incubating-SNAPSHOT.jar' failed
make: *** [target/scala-2.11/toree-assembly-0.2.0.dev1-incubating-SNAPSHOT.jar] Error 1
root@ubuntu-2gb-sgp1-01:/home/incubator-toree#
```

I have docker installed

```
root@ubuntu-2gb-sgp1-01:/home/incubator-toree# docker -v
Docker version 1.12.3, build 6b644ec
```

Comment: Did you try to use Oracle JDK for this?

Comment: Hi Viktor, I managed to get it working in the end. had to compile into a package and install with pip

Comment: Great news, congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to build and compile Toree, since it's provided a built package already.

Dev snapshots of Toree are located at https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/incubator/toree. To install using one of those packages, you can use the following:

```
pip install <PIP_RELEASE_URL>

jupyter toree install
```

where PIP_RELEASE_URL is one of the pip packages. For example:

```
pip install https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/incubator/toree/0.2.0/snapshots/dev1/toree-pip/toree-0.2.0.dev1.tar.gz
jupyter toree install --spark_home=$SPARK_HOME
```